# TYPO3 backend form module gives error when creating forms

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm currently running TYPO3 version 8.7.18 and running a site_package that was made by using the site package builder: [link](https://sitepackagebuilder.com/)

Whenever I try to add a form by using the default backend forms module I get the default message `Oops, an error occurred!` along with that the following error

`TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Configuration\FormDefinition\Converters\AddHmacDataConverter not found`

Searching for the issue I get several hits on the Gitlab but these do not provide any solution.

Along with this setup, I've added the forms module as a static include in my top-level template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error turned out to be caused by a corrupt installation. I've had to upload the file `AddHmacDataConverter.php` in the following path `/public_html/typo3/sysext/form/Classes/Domain/Configuration/FormDefinition/Converters`. A very weird error indeed.

For those that came here with the same error, make sure to check that folder. Apart from that add the news as a static inclusion in your top domain. You could also follow @Bernd Wilke's idea which s to disable the extension, clear all system caches (and additionally remove `typo3/temp/autoload` and then active the extension again.

Answer (score 1):

do you have a composer installation or an extension manager build up?

If a class is not found you may need to rebuild the autoloader information.

Comment: Is there any way I can check this? I believe I have an extension manager build up.


Where could I find information on rebuilding autoloader information?

Comment: in an extension manager build up you only need to vary the list of active extensions (just disable and enable one extension). to be sure clear all system caches before. Alternatively you could delete the autoload folder (`typo3temp/autoload/`) if it exists.

Comment: I'll try this solution; apart from always needing to back up, is there anything that could specifically go wrong with deleting the autoload folder?

Comment: Deactivating / Activating the plugin doesn't seem to have done anything. And no autload folder seems to be available in `typo3temp/autoload/` I do have an autload folder in `typo3conf/autoload/`

Comment: Alright as it turned out by deactivating / activating the plugin I did get error messages. It was a file that was missing at typo3's core. By following this error I found that in the folder : `/public_html/typo3/sysext/form/Classes/Domain/Configuration/FormDefinition/Converters` the file `AddHmacDataConverter.php` was missing. I've added it from a clean typo3 installation and all works perfectly. 

Thank you for helping me debug this issue, you can edit with the solution if you'd want to

Comment: that is a strange error. normaly no files should get lost from an installation. and the solution has nothing to do with my answer. add an answer yourself :)

Comment: Yes, i'll need to figure out what happend to my installation anyways.

Alright I will. Thanks again!